# Проблема создания модели ADO.NET EDM из базы данных MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework, mysqlconnector

Необходима работать с базой данных MySql с помощью Entity Framework. Версия платформы: .Net Framework 4.0, Visual Studio 2019 (параллельно установлена 2017).

С офф сайта скачал:

1. MySQL for Visual Studio v.1.2.8 ;
2. MySQL connector/NET v.6.9.10 (указано, что поддерживает версии .Net framework 4.0 и 4.5).
3. MySQL Server v.8.0.17

Установил всё в таком же порядке. После создания проекта добавил через nuget Entity Framework 6.3, затем из папки с установленной MySQL connector/NET подтягиваю ссылки MySql.Data.dll и MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll.

В App.config вставляю строчку вместо существующей

```
<entityFramework>
   <providers>
     <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
          type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
   </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Всё сохраняю, делаю ребилд.

Создаю подключение к БД через Обозреватель серверов:

1. Источник данных - MySQL Database
2. Поставщик данных - .NET Framework Data Provider for MySQL
3. Затем добавляю подключение - Всё отлично! К БД подключиться можем, через обозреватель можно просмотреть таблицы, связи и всё остальное.

Теперь пытаюсь создать ADO.NET EDM модель, содержащую Конструктор EF из базы. данных)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь, после нажатия "Далее" появляется следующее окно буквально на секунду и пропадает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После исчезновения окна ничего не добавляется и не меняется. То же самое происходит, используя создание модели CodeFirst из базы данных, или, создав новую пустую модель и потом пробуя сохранить её в БД.

Пробовал решить проблему по следующей инструкции, со всеми указанными версиями (ссылка на qaru, который здесь запрещён):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат тот же!

PS. Когда устанавливаю все последние версии файлов и библиотек, и не меняю в App.config строки данных провайдеров - создаю модель, содержащую Конструктор EF из базы - но на последнем окне выдаёт ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение данной проблемы. На офф. сайте MySql есть [инструкция](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

Проверено, работает отлично!!!

Comment: Вот кросавчег автор вопроса - не просто нашел решение, а еще и нам сказал! Спасибо! Кстати, Вы можете "принять" собственный ответ. Это увеличивает "ценность" вопроса (хорошо, когда у вопроса есть "более достоверный" ответ) и даже добавляет Вам чуть чуть рейтинга